# a home page display only partial page but not display own page with partial page, why?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4. I want to know why a home page (Index) only shows partial page (_PersonGrid), but not index page with the div loading the partial page?? What have I done wrong with my code? I have noticed that ajax not fire event "loading page".

```
public class ViewModels
{

    public IEnumerable<Person> VmPersonList { get; set; }

 }
```

**Controller: Home**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        _viewModels.VmPersonList = Repository.GetPersons();


        return PartialView("_PersonGrid", _viewModels.VmPersonList);

    }
```

**View: _PersonGrid.cshtml**

```
   @model IEnumerable<ManagementProgram.Areas.Persons.Models.Person> 

  @{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model, defaultSort: "Id", rowsPerPage: 10, canSort: false);
   }

@if (Model != null)
{
    @grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "grid",
          columns:grid.Columns(
    grid.Column("Id", header: "Person ID"),
    grid.Column(columnName: "Description", header: "Name"),
    grid.Column(columnName: "Department", header: "Department Name")
    ))

}
```

**View: Index**

//Here not display but only display partial page without "Hello World", why? I need to display index page including "Hello World" with the partial page (webgrid) like this:

#### HELLO WORLD

```
<div id="insidecontent">
  <div id="gridcontent"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

   // Here not firing event.
    $(document).ready(function () {
    alert('Loading Page');
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            $('#gridcontent').html(data);
        }
    });

});

</script>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<int> selectedCountryId)
    {
        try
        {
            IEnumerable<Person> persons = new List<Person>();


            var db = Repository.GetPersonData(selectedCountryId);


            return PartialView("_PersonGrid", persons);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }


    }
```

View:

```
   @Html.DropDownList("Countries", "-----Select Country-----")
```

Javascript:

```
    $(document).on('change', '#Countries', function () {
        var selectedCountry= $("#Countries").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { selectedCountryId: selectedCountry},
            success: function (data) {
                $('#gridcontent').html(data);
            }
        });

    });
```

**Step 1:** open a page to load all the person list from _PersonGrid where I am struggling with -- to load this data on the page (div gridcontent) using ajax calling Partial View instead of loading the whole page. I explored that document.ready wont work in partial. I am not sure how to load data into div gridcontent using ajax calling Partial View.

**Step 2:** select a Country Name to get a list of persons (Ajax POST works fine)

Comment: I think because you are returning the partial view:
return PartialView("_PersonGrid", _viewModels.VmPersonList);
Try with 
return PartialView(_viewModels.VmPersonList);

Comment: now the loading event is fired, thanks but load the whole html page instead of loading specific div tag. Is my ajax code correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can call renderAction inside #gridcontent. You will be a better performance and a better compatibility to create the entire view server-side instead of call the rest of the view client-side in your case .(if your explanation is complete)

So, i don't test that but try something like :

```
 <div id="insidecontent">
     <div id="gridcontent">@{ Html.renderAction("Index","Home"); }</div>
 </div>
```

and remove your script :

```
    // Here not firing event.
$(document).ready(function () {
  alert('Loading Page');
  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        $('#gridcontent').html(data);
    }
});
```

});

## UPDATE

### HomeController

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult GetPersonTable()
    {
        List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
        {
            persons.Add(new Person(i,"Desc "+i,"depart "+i)); 
        }            

        return PartialView("_PersonGrid", persons);
    }
}
```

### _PersonGrid

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication.Models.Person>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "_PersonGrid";
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model, defaultSort: "Id", rowsPerPage: 10, canSort: false);
}

<h2>_PersonGrid</h2>

@if(Model!=null)
{
    @grid.GetHtml("grid",null,null,null,null,null,null,true,false,null,grid.Columns(
    grid.Column("Id","Person ID"),
    grid.Column("Description","Name"),
    grid.Column("Department","Department Name")));
}
```

### Index home

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@section featured {
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
                <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
            </hgroup>
            @{ Html.RenderAction("GetPersonTable"); }
        </div>
    </section>
}
<h3>We suggest the following:</h3>
<ol class="round">
    <li class="one">
        <h5>Getting Started</h5>
        ASP.NET MVC gives you a powerful, patterns-based way to build dynamic websites that
        enables a clean separation of concerns and that gives you full control over markup
        for enjoyable, agile development. ASP.NET MVC includes many features that enable
        fast, TDD-friendly development for creating sophisticated applications that use
        the latest web standards.
        <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=245151">Learn more…</a>
    </li>
[...]
```

### Image

[image: the result]

[You can download here the project](http://ul.to/rmhizfha)

The pagination work too.

I hope that'll hope you

Comment: your solution is not working for me. Nothing happens but only repeat to run the index method until it crashes.

Comment: where is the view who contain : `<div id="insidecontent"> <div id="gridcontent"></div></div>` ?

Comment: already update it. hope u can give me a good example. i been struggling the whole day. sigh